# Flatten processing result in spring batch

Tags: java, spring-batch

Does anyone know how in spring-batch (3.0.7) can I flat a result of processor that returns list of entities? 
Example:

I got a processor that returns List

```
public class MyProcessor implements ItemProcessor < Long , List <Entity>> {
    public List<Entity> process ( Long id )
}
```

Now all following processors / writers need to work on List < Entity >. Is there any way to flat the result to simply Entity so the further processors in given step can work on single Entities?

The only way is to persist the list somehow with a writer and then create a separate step that would read from the persisted data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting question. I'm having exactly the same problem. I'm wondering why this question has been down voted two times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, processors in spring-batch can be chained with a composite processor. Within the chain, you can change the processing type from processor to processor, but of course input and output type of two "neighbour"-processors have to match.

However, Input out Output type  is always treated as one item. Therefore, if the output type of a processor ist a List, this list is regared as one item. Hence, the following processor needs to have an InputType "List", resp., if a writer follows, the Writer needs to have a List-of-List as type its write-method.
Moreover, a processor can not multiply its element. There can only be one output item for every input element.

Basically, there is nothing wrong with having a chain like

```
Reader<Integer>
ProcessorA<Integer,List<Integer>>
ProcessorB<List<Integer>,List<Integer>>
Writer<List<Integer>> (which leads to a write-method write(List<List<Integer>> items)
```

Depending on the context, there could be a better solution.
You could mitigate the impact (for instance reuseability) by using wrapper-processors and a wrapper-writer like the following code examples:

```
public class ListWrapperProcessor<I,O> implements ItemProcessor<List<I>, List<O>> {

    ItemProcessor<I,O> delegate;

    public void setDelegate(ItemProcessor<I,O> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }


    public List<O> process(List<I> itemList) {
        List<O> outputList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (I item : itemList){    
           O outputItem = delegate.process(item);
           if (outputItem!=null) {
               outputList.add(outputItem);
           }
        }

        if (outputList.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        return outputList;
    }

}


public class ListOfListItemWriter<T> implements InitializingBean, ItemStreamWriter<List<T>> {

    private ItemStreamWriter<T> itemWriter;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends List<T>> listOfLists) throws Exception {
        if (listOfLists.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        List<T> all = listOfLists.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());

        itemWriter.write(all);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull(itemWriter, "The 'itemWriter' may not be null");
    }

    public void setItemWriter(ItemStreamWriter<T> itemWriter) {
        this.itemWriter = itemWriter;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        this.itemWriter.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
        this.itemWriter.open(executionContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
        this.itemWriter.update(executionContext);
    }
}
```

Using such wrappers, you could still implement "normal" processor and writers and then use such wrappers in order to move the "List"-handling out of them.

Comment: Thanks for comprehend explanation. I implemented my case in similar way (using wrapper objects to make easier tracking of retry/error handling) It's not what I was expecting in the first place (since counting/skipping functionality need to be implemented specially for that case) but I suppose there is no way to do any better because of spring-batch restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can provide a compelling reason, there's no reason to send a List of Lists to your `ItemWriter`. This is not the way the `ItemProcessor` was intended to be used. Instead, you should create/configure and `ItemReader` to return one object with relevant objects.

For example, if you're reading from the database, you could use the `HibernateCursorItemReader` and a query that looks something like this:

```
"from ParentEntity parent left join fetch parent.childrenEntities"
```

Your data model SHOULD have a parent table with the `Long id` that you're currently passing to your `ItemProcessor`, so leverage that to your advantage. The reader would then pass back `ParentEntity` objects, each with a collection of `ChildEntity` objects that go along with it.

Comment: I know item processor/writer shouldn't be used with lists but the situation I got is following: I got table in database with ids which I query one by one, and then for each id I invoke remote rest service (in processor) which could return multiple items - which forces me to return list.

Comment: That unfortunately breaks the pattern of `Reader->Processor->Writer`. I would instead configure a custom `ItemReader` to do those rest calls and return 1 item at a time to your processor. Hansjoerg's answer could also work, but I'd prefer not passing `List<List<T>>` to my writer.